# what would cause migrations to do nothing except keep the correct version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, migration, rails-migrations

I have an app that I was first writing in rails 3.1 but in an effort to reduce my slug size on heroku I generated a new rails 3.0.9 app and manually moved over the necessary code (or so I thought).  Everything worked as expected for over a month but i had been using rake db:schema:load because I hadn't changed the db schema.  Today I tried to change my schema and migrations are doing nothing.  They appear to think they are running and they are keeping track of versions but I get no output to the console and no changes to the db, also the schema.rb file is unchanged.

`rake db:migrate --trace` actually says `** Execute db:schema:dump` as the last step, but the schema.rb file still does not have the column I was trying to add.  Does anyone have any idea what is going on?  The app is connected to a database, and everything is working fine I just can't seem to run any migrations.  I could change the schema.rb file and run rake:db:load again but I would like to avoid losing data on the production deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrations for Rails 3.1 can use a `Migration#change` method that knows how to do both an up and down migration. In 3.0, you'll need to have a separate `Migration.up` and `Migration.down` methods. You should be able to change the `change` to `up` and then write the `down` section.

As tee pointed out, you'll need to make sure to change `def change` to `def self.up` and `def self.down` since the older migration methods are class rather than instance methods.

Comment: I actually just explained this to someone in the IRC channel and a light bulb went off in my head.  Thanks Emily, I feel dumb ;) Time to go change them.

Comment: I just got bit by this too. Note that up/down are class methods, so change "def change" to "def self.up" and add "def self.down".